# PySerial RS-485 read

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

Hello I want to make a RS-485 transmission with two devices FT232(they are connected via USB with Raspberry Pi 3 but also with RJ45 - I wanted only check that transmission works properly. Im trying to use PySerial with RS485 function from https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/rs485.py

I tried to create own read but probadly write and read transmission didn't work (program didn't shows receiving data). There is read function:

```
def read(self,n):
    print(n)
    if self._alternate_rs485_settings is not None:
        self.setRTS(self._alternate_rs485_settings.rts_level_for_rx)
        if self._alternate_rs485_settings.delay_before_rx is not None:
            time.sleep(self._alternate_rs485_settings.delay_before_rx)
        response = super(RS485, self).read(size=n)
        super(RS485, self).flush()
        if self._alternate_rs485_settings.delay_before_tx is not None:
            time.sleep(self._alternate_rs485_settings.delay_before_tx)
        self.setRTS(self._alternate_rs485_settings.rts_level_for_tx)
    else:
        super(RS485, self).read()
    return response
```

I used setRTS to changing transmit and receiving port (because I wanted to make RS-485, half-duplex transmission)

How to write and read properly data?

Comment: How does the device's response latency affect communication faster than your digital output? At this point your data sending speed is very important. This example writes a friend timeout and hardware latency and receive delay, mixing them all. There is absolutely no receive delay in bus communication.(Minimum delay is 1ms on hardvare IO, AND @9600bps frequency is 19200hz mean 52microSeconds time gap)

Comment: Most of the problem you're asking is not about Python, get a full-duplex converter, or make your converter a fully-duplex. There were hardware descriptions if you hadn't deleted the previous question.

Comment: I set baudrate to 9600. Could u tell me how delay should be look? Im still don't know how to fix that. I can't make fully duplex because I want half-duplex to check that transmission works properly. I restored last post, but u sent me information about automatically RTS with capacitor. Im not using adapters, just plugged devices to RPi 3 via USB and in the future I wanted to connect pins with devices via rs485

Comment: I have no idea how to describe it. Hardware or communication delays on the Kernel are not always equal. It makes more sense to use the UART ports on raspberry (at least you can do a quick I/O). To do this, you need to use an integrated SN75176BP or similar (MAX14945 etc.). There's a lot of difference between a USB connection on a Linux USB serial device. If you use it as a serial port, you won't be able to quickly access the digital pins of the device. You should examine the technical documentation of the converters you use (you have not specified the full IC name)

Comment: Okay now Im understand You, but I wanted to transmit except integrated devices, because I must check transmission as fast as possible, that I asked how to read by using PySerial and RS485 functions

Comment: under the `else` statement, you forgot to assign to the variable `response`

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo ok thanks but there isn't a problem. Maybe I not properly call read function? I think that I have bad implement delay or read but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: How does he know that the last bit of the package is transmitted ?
 (on_Start_Transmit_delay and on_End_Transmit_Delay will not work you!) , how you know your device RTS pin connected to `RE an DE` pin(on RS485 chip) ?  **This type of communication does not guarantee a full packet of receiving or sending.** No delays in communication, either sending or receiving data.

Comment: Holy... so u tell me that I can't properly transmit data without indicators?? I must send only one string, just one line. I tried to make transmission with PySerial but without RS485 function and it also didnt receive. But I think that I bad implement that :(

Comment: Exactly, `RS485` function is garbage. so this function only do :  on send `def _send(msg): ser.RTS = True ; ser.write(msg); time.sleep(_your_delay); ser.RTS=False;time.sleep(_your_delay);return ser.read(ser.inWaiting()) `